# Google analytics dynamic php, where to include code?

Tags: php, dynamic, google-analytics

The question has been asked before but none of the previous answers that I have found solves my problem.
This is the structure for my web page.
index.php calls the loader.
loader.tpl generates `<head>`, generates `<body>` by include header.tpl, include $body and include footer.
A separate php page holds the functions and a new page is generated by calling a function that sets $page to a new value matching a .tpl file.

I've created the analyticstracking.php file and placed it in a folder.
I've tried placing`<?php include_once("foldername/analyticstracking.php") ?>`  pretty much in every place I can think of. Either it doesn't do anything at all or it causes an error.
No error code is given, it only returns a blank grey page.

I tried copying the script code straight into the body of the $page template and it only generated an error.

I'm out of ideas.
Where should I place 
Since I've tried any number of different locations, it would be great if you could give an answer so foolproof that it can't be miss interpreted.
Thanks

Comment: You mentioned trying to copy the script code straight into the body - can you show the code itself?  And the specific error message?

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: No error code is printed, I just get a grey screen. Showing the code itself is tricky since it's spread over several files and each file is easily 50-100 rows of code, some several hundred lines of code.